# Load a core dump continue running

Tags: process, core-dump

I can [create a coredump as a snapshot of a process's image and continue running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131439/how-can-a-c-program-produce-a-core-dump-of-itself-without-terminating/131539#131539).
Can I then, on another run of the program load the coredump and continue at that same point in time? If so how?

Ultimately what I would like to do is use the coredump as a fast initialization tool.
For example, imagine something like this:

```
main() {
   if (this is the first time the program has run) {
       Load massive database and other initialization
       Create coredump
   } else {
       Load coredump
   }
   Do process specific thing
}
```

I think [emacs used to do something like this](https://lwn.net/Articles/707619/)? Any ideas?